# Comparator.compareBoolean() the same as Comparator.compare()?

Tags: java-8, comparator

How can I write this

```
Comparator <Item> sort = (i1, i2) -> Boolean.compare(i2.isOpen(), i1.isOpen());
```

to something like this (code does not work):

```
Comparator<Item> sort = Comparator.comparing(Item::isOpen).reversed();
```

Comparing method does not have something like Comparator.comparingBool(). Comparator.comparing returns int and not "Item".

Comment: `Comparator.comparing` can not return `int` - it returns a `Comparator<T>`. No methods of comparator class are able to return `Item`. Also, when saying "code does not work" you should include **how** it does not work. I don't see any problem with that code, you have two roughly equivalent code blocks.

Comment: Was my fault. I had wrong code before in the editor and placed the right code here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why can't you write it like this?

```
 Comparator<Item> sort = Comparator.comparing(Item::isOpen);
```

Underneath `Boolean.compareTo` is called, which in turn is the same as `Boolean.compare`

```
public static int compare(boolean x, boolean y) {
    return (x == y) ? 0 : (x ? 1 : -1);
}
```

And this: `Comparator.comparing returns int and not "Item".` make little sense, `Comparator.comparing` *must* return a `Comparator<T>`; in your case it correctly returns a `Comparator<Item>`.

Comment: Thanks. Executes "Boolean.compare(i2.isOpen(), i1.isOpen());" faster than "Comparator.comparing(Item::isOpen);"?

Comment: I am wondering because I am using the ".reversed()" which I do not need in the first version. So comparator traverses the whole list after comparing..

Comment: Okay i checked it and reverseOrder calls function identical to my first version so no traversing. It s the same.

Comment: @nimo23, I wouldn't worry about whether a lambda is "faster" than method reference: you're unlikely to notice the difference, and both versions are subject to runtime optimizations that complicate things even more.

Answer (score 6):

The overloads `comparingInt`, `comparingLong`, and `comparingDouble` exist for performance reasons only. They are semantically identical to the unspecialized `comparing` method, so using `comparing` instead of `comparingXXX` has the same outcome, but might having boxing overhead, but the actual implications depend on the particular execution environment.

In case of `boolean` values, we can predict that the overhead will be negligible, as the method `Boolean.valueOf` will always return either `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE` and never create new instances, so even if a particular JVM fails to inline the entire code, it does not depend on the presence of Escape Analysis in the optimizer.

As you already figured out, reversing a comparator is implemented by swapping the argument internally, just like you did manually in your lambda expression.

Note that it is still possible to create a comparator fusing the reversal and an unboxed comparison without having to repeat the `isOpen()` expression:

```
Comparator<Item> sort = Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.isOpen()? 0: 1);
```

but, as said, it’s unlikely to have a significantly higher performance than the `Comparator.comparing(Item::isOpen).reversed()` approach.

---

But note that if you have a `boolean` sort criteria and care for the maximum performance, you may consider replacing the general-purpose sort algorithm with a bucket sort variant. E.g.

If you have a Stream, replace

```
List<Item> result = /* stream of Item */
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::isOpen).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with

```
Map<Boolean,List<Item>> map = /* stream of Item */
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Item::isOpen,
                                       Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
List<Item> result = map.get(true);
result.addAll(map.get(false));
```

or, if you have a `List`, replace

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::isOpen).reversed());
```

with

```
ArrayList<Item> temp = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
list.removeIf(item -> !item.isOpen() && temp.add(item));
list.addAll(temp);
```

etc.

Comment: I like how you have used `&& temp.add(item)`, even if you really don't care about the result of `temp.add(item)`

Answer (score 2):

Use comparing using key extractor parameter:

```
Comparator<Item> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparing(Item::isOpen, Boolean::compare).reversed();
```

Comment: No need in `Boolean::compare` there: `Boolean` class is-a `Comparable<Boolean>`, and uses `Boolean::compare` as its natural ordering anyway.